# How are global variables stored?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, memory, global

AFAIK, there're 2 types of global variables, *initialized* and *unintialized*. How are they stored? Are they both stored in the executable file? I can think of initialized global variables having their initial values stored in executable file. But what needs to be stored for the uninitialized ones?

My current understanding is like this:

Executable file is organized as several sections, such as .text, .data, and .bss. Code is stored in .text section, initialized global or static data is stored in .data section, and uninitialized global or static data is stored in .bss section.

Thanks for your time to view my questions.

### Update 1 - 9:56 AM 11/3/2010

I found a good reference here:

[Segments in Assembly Language Source - 
Building the text and data segments with .text, .data, and .bss directives](http://www.enchantedlearning.com/sparc/segments/segmentsassembly.shtml)

### Update 2 - 10:09 AM 11/3/2010

@Michael

1. I define a 100 bytes of un-initialized data area in my assembly code, this 100-bytes is not stored in my executable file because it is NOT initialized.
2. Who will allocate the 100-byte uninitialized memory space in RAM? The *program loader*?

Suppose I got the following code:

```
int global[100];

void main(void)
{
   //...
}
```

The global[100] is not initialzed. How will the global[100] be recoded in my executable file? And who will allocate it at what time? What if it is initialized?

Comment: Usually there is also `.rdata` segment for `const` variables (sorry for oxymoron).

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281925/what-is-default-storage-class-for-global-variables

Comment: `void main` is neither legal C nor legal C++. The return type of `main` must **always** be `int`.

Answer (score 11):

Initialized variable values are stored in the `.data` segment of the executable. Uninitialized ones *don't have to be stored*. They end up in the `.bss` segment in RAM, but the size of the segment is zero in the executable file, just the required amount of memory is stored in the segment descriptor. The code in the `.text` section is accessing these *via offsets* into the segment. [Runtime linker-loader](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6463) patches these references to actual [virtual addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). See, for example, the [Executable and Linkable Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), which is used on most Unix-like operating systems.

Comment: very platform specific answer without mentioning that fact

Comment: and memory is flat, not segmented

Comment: There's always a doubt haunting me: If nothing is stored for the un-initialized data in my executable file, how could the operating-system know what to allocate in RAM at runtime?

Comment: @Andrey, yes, the virtual address space is virtually flat :) Then there are MMUs, pages, TLBs, caches, NUMA, and all that fun. The process VA space is still partitioned. That's why you get *segmentation violations* :)

Comment: @smwikipedia, read the ELF spec (or COFF, or whatever) - the executable stores the *size* of the `.bss`.

Comment: @Nicolai, That's just what I am thinking! The *size* of .bss is stored.

Comment: I would add to this that if the global is declared as a const it can and/or does show up in .text not as a reference but that is its home.  Basically, globals can land in all three, .data, .bss, and .text.  Often if uninitialized in the code the program/loader zeros that memory space giving you a zero.  I would not rely on that and compilers are now starting to give good warnings about use of variables before being initialized.

Comment: @Andrey: he's not talking about OS memory organization, he's talking about the linker's memory map: linkers group data + program memory allocation into segments such as .bss, .data, .text, etc.

Answer (score 3):

In PE files there are two sizes specified for each segment: RAWsize (size on disk) and Vsize (size in RAM).

When `Vsize` is larger than the `RAWsize`, the rest of segment in RAM is zeroed.

`.bss` (if present) always has RAWsize of 0, and the uninialized globlal variables are located there.

Another common approach is to make `Vsize` of `.data` larger than its `RAWsize`, so that the rest of the segment will hold unitialized variables.

Comment: It's kind of a paradox. Though RAWsize is 0 for .bss segment, .bss segment **actually** occupies space on disk. Otherwise, no clue (I would call it *meta-clue*) could be recorded for .bss segment.

Comment: ELF works the same way; normally the `.bss` section is just part of the same segment as `.data`, in the part after the "filesiz", but within the "memsiz"  (`readelf -a /bin/ls` for an example: look for a segment with RW permissions and a memsiz greater than filesiz.)

Answer (score 2):

Storage for global variables is allocated in your computer's virtual memory by the OS linker/loader at the time your program is loaded.  The actual global variable storage is somewhere in the physical memory hierarchy (cache, RAM memory, SSD/HD backing storage, etc.), as mapped by the cache and VM system.  It could all end up quite fragmented.

The values of initialized globals are copied from the .data segment into a portion of the allocated virtual memory.  Non-initialized globals might be zeroed, or might have junk left in them, depending on the security of the particular OS under which the program is running.

The are other variations, depending on the language, compiler, language run-time, and OS.

Comment: Thanks for your concise reply. Things are much clearer. So conceptually speaking, the OS loader layout the process's virtual address space according to the process' backing executable file. If so, the **size info** of the uninitialized data must be recorded in the exe file, though its value is left undecided. Am I right?

Comment: I think I need to check some exe file format such as PE to see if things go like I expected.

Comment: @smwikipedia, static compiled languages can have the size of the data (if known at compile time) stored somewhere in the binary.  But there also exist dynamic and interpreted languages that don't allocate space (and fix up the linkages) until a global variable is actually encountered in execution.

Comment: your reply explained *when* the global variables are allocated, that's very helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Uninitialized variables are simply pointers at the machine level. The space for them is allocated at runtime, and the program will fill it in at some later time.

For instance, if in assembler you create a global variable `global BYTE 100` that will reserve `global` as a pointer to a 100 byte region. The program then has access to that region for whatever it needs.

EDIT: I looked up in my assembler book and it looks like uninitialized globals are defined in the .data section just as initialized variables are. From my understanding the space is allocated in the exe (say 100 bytes as above) but will have undefined contents. On Intel machines in Windows it will be garbage; the program is responsible for initializing it. Hope this helps!