# Malloced global variable implementation (C)

Tags: c, global-variables

I would like to make a linked list globally available across multiple .c files.

I've read how to do this but I can't identify what is causing my problem.

I declare the variable with extern in LinkedList.h:

```
extern LinkedList* canQueue;
```

And then in main.c I initialise the variable by sending it to a function in LinkedList.c like so:

```
LinkedList *canQueue=createList();
```

This is the create function in LinkedList.c:

```
LinkedList* createList() /*creates empty linked list*/
  {
    LinkedList* myList;
    myList = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
    myList->head = NULL;
    return myList;
  }
```

I then want to use the canQueue in another file, cpu.c. I've included LinkedList.h in the cpu.c, so at this point the Linked List should be available here from what I know. But when I try to access it I get an error:

```
undefined reference to 'canQueue'
```

Have I missed something or done something wrong?

Comment: Also please not I have to use the global variable for this problem, so simply not using one is not a good solution for me.

Comment: You need to *define* your variable (once in a .c file, with no `extern`) in addition to *declaring* it.

Comment: Why do those ugly guys in robot outfits show up whenever I want to answer a question in a jiffy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you simply don't define such a global variable. If this code compiles:

```
LinkedList *canQueue = createList();
```

then it's not a "global" (file-scope) variable. Define it at file scope and initialize it carefully so you don't shadow it with a local variable. All in all, do something like this:

```
// at global scope
LinkedList *canQueue;

void initialize() // or whatever
{
    canQueue = createList();
}
```

Comment: Good point. Now that I've changed it to `LinkedList *cpuQueue `, I still get the undefined reference errors so I've done something wrong with the declaration.

Comment: @Dawson Definitely. Make sure it isn't `static`, it's *actually* declared as `extern` in the header, etc.

Comment: @Dawson "Now that I've changed it to LinkedList *cpuQueue" .. it's a different name ...  where did you change it? in .h or .c?

Comment: sorry I mean canQueue, I changed the declaration in main.c

Comment: @H2CO3 Can you tell me something plain and simple.What storage class variables declared at file scope have? **extern** or **static**.I read in many places that global variables have **extern** storage class by default,but a 80k reputation user on SO tells me they have default **static** storage.

Comment: @H2CO3 I think I got the exact answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281925/what-is-default-storage-class-for-global-variables

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture `extern`, unless declared as `static`.

Comment: @H2CO3 `LinkedList *canQueue = createList();` will this line compile? file scope variables should have constant expression as initializers right?

Comment: @Koushik Apparently that line was at function scope -- read the second sentence in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign a **constant** to a global variable when initializing it.And `return` of a function is not considered a **constant**.So the following will show error:

```
 LinkedList *canQueue=createList();
```

**Edit** I missed it that you have declared and initialized the pointer `*canQueue` at `function scope` instead of `file scope`.That goes against the very definition of a `global variable`.But there's one more catch.If you declare something like `LinkedList *canQueue=createList();` at the file-scope, you'll get the following error:

```
     Initializer element not constant
```

Since the object will be "declared" at file scope, it has static storage duration. Initializers for objects of static storage duration must be constant expressions. The result of a function call is not a constant expression

Comment: It didn't error out - the problem is that `canQueue` wasn't really a "global" (file-scope) variable.

Comment: Oops, it missed it that he has defined the variable in `main()`!! LOL..There is no way it will be global.