# Global variable belongs to which storage type in c?

Tags: c, variables, declaration, linkage, storage-duration

Want to know in C programming language declaring a global variable without static, belongs to which storage type out of auto, extern, static, reg?

Comment: easily searched, dupe of [What is default storage class for global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281925/what-is-default-storage-class-for-global-variables)

Comment: Properly speaking, C does not have any truly “global” variables. That word is not used in the C standard regarding identifiers. The standard uses different concepts of scope and linkage to describe properties of identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Such a variable has external linkage and static storage duration. It may be initialized by a constant expression or string literal.

From the C Standard (6.2.2 Linkages of identifiers)

> 5 If the declaration of an identifier for a function has no
> storage-class specifier, its linkage is determined exactly as if it
> were declared with the storage-class specifier extern. **If the
> declaration of an identifier for an object has file scope and no
> storage-class specifier, its linkage is external.**

and (6.2.4 Storage durations of objects)

> 3 An object whose identifier is declared without the storage-class
> specifier _Thread_local, and either with external or internal linkage
> or with the storage-class specifier static, has static storage
> duration. Its lifetime is the entire execution of the program and its
> stored value is initialized only once, prior to program startup

and at last (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 4 All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static
> or thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string
> literals.